# How to enable Location automatically within app without going to device settings page

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy

How to enable Location automatically within app without navigating to device settings page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with the current SDK without any external module or Hyperloop. You can search at http://gitt.io/ or https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/home but I don't think there is a module available. You have to create one yourself (or again, try it with hyperloop)